# Dojo validation that depends on another widget value

Tags: widget, constraints, dojo

I have a widget with validation params such as "min" and "max". I want "min" to be set dynamically, because it depends on value contained in another widget.

```
<input id="test" type="text"
    data-dojo-type="dijit/form/NumberTextBox"
    name= "elevation"
    required="true"
    value="3000"
    data-dojo-props="constraints:{min:-20000,max:20000,places:0},
    invalidMessage:'Invalid elevation.'" />
```

How can I do something like min: testWidget.getValue()

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is use the `_WidgetBase#set` method. Here is the description from Dojo's API documentation:

> Set a property on a widget
>   Sets named properties on a widget which may potentially be handled by a setter in the widget.
>
> For example, if the widget has properties "foo" and "bar" and a method named _setFooAttr(), calling myWidget.set("foo", "Howdy!") would be equivalent to calling widget._setFooAttr("Howdy!") and myWidget.set("bar", 3) would be equivalent to the statement widget.bar = 3;
>
> set() may also be called with a hash of name/value pairs, ex:

So with your widget reference you can simply do:

```
var elevationInput = dijit.byId("test");
var constraints = {
  min: testWidget.getValue(); // or testWidget.get("value")
  max: elevationInput.constraints.max
};
elevationInput.set("constraints", constraints);
```